# mysql error message when a table is missing is different in different machine

Tags: mysql

Machine 1: `Table 'SomeSchema.SomeTable' doesn't exist`

Machine 2: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1017 Can't find file 'SomeSchema/SomeTable.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)`

Both of errors seems related to a missing table but why is not consistent?

Comment: What are the OS of both hosts, versions of MySQL?

Comment: machine 1:
OS:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ||
MYSQL: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
||||||||||||
machine 2: 
OS: probably OSX. not sure. sorry. ||
MYSQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.34, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Maybe this is the reason (different OS, different version)